# Modal undecorated window

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I would like to create Modal window like this:

[image]

So far I only managed to create undecorated stage

```
public  void initEditStage(){

        Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(new Button("my second window")), Color.AQUA));
        stage.show();


    }
```

How I can create the back window barely readable like the picture?

Comment: There you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571593/drop-shadow-in-an-undecorated-pane-javafx

Answer (score 3):

Just grab the root of the scene of the main stage and add a blur effect to it. Reset the effect when you dismiss the dialog. There's a bunch of ways you could approach this but here's a (complete) example that more or less does the minimum.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.effect.BoxBlur;
import javafx.scene.effect.Effect;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.stage.Window;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class BlurWindowWithDialog extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = createUI();

        Button showDialogButton = new Button("Show Dialog");
        showDialogButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            Parent rootPane = showDialogButton.getScene().getRoot();
            Effect previousEffect = rootPane.getEffect();
            final BoxBlur blur = new BoxBlur(0, 0, 5);
            blur.setInput(previousEffect);
            rootPane.setEffect(blur);

            Stage stage = createDialog(showDialogButton.getScene().getWindow());
            stage.setOnHidden(t -> rootPane.setEffect(previousEffect));

            // Optional extra: fade the blur and dialog in:
            stage.getScene().getRoot().setOpacity(0);
            Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), 
                    new KeyValue(blur.widthProperty(), 10), 
                    new KeyValue(blur.heightProperty(), 10),
                    new KeyValue(stage.getScene().getRoot().opacityProperty(), 0.75)
            ));
            timeline.play();

            stage.show();
        });
        HBox bottomControls = new HBox(5, showDialogButton);
        bottomControls.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        bottomControls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        root.setBottom(bottomControls);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Stage createDialog(Window owner) {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initOwner(owner);
        stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        Button okButton = new Button("OK");
        okButton.setOnAction(evt -> stage.hide() );
        VBox dialogRoot = new VBox(5, new Label("You pressed the button"), okButton);
        dialogRoot.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        dialogRoot.setStyle("-fx-background-color: derive(lightsteelblue, 25%) ; -fx-border-color: blue;"
                    + "-fx-background-radius: 8px; -fx-border-radius: 8px; -fx-border-width: 3px;");
        final Scene scene = new Scene(dialogRoot, 250, 150,
                Color.TRANSPARENT);
        enableDragging(scene);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        return stage;
    }

    private BorderPane createUI() {
        HBox topControls = new HBox(5, 
                new Label("Label"),
                new Button("Button"), 
                new ComboBox<String>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("One", "Two", "Three")),
                new Button("Another Button"), 
                new Label("Another Label"));
        topControls.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        topControls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        String loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, "
                + "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. "
                + "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris "
                + "nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in "
                + "reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. "
                + "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, "
                + "sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
        TextArea bigLabel = new TextArea(loremIpsum);
        bigLabel.setWrapText(true);
        bigLabel.setPadding(new Insets(20));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(bigLabel, topControls, null, null, null);
        root.setStyle("-fx-base: #b2cdf7; -fx-border-color: blue; -fx-border-width: 3px ;");
        return root;
    }

    private void enableDragging(Scene scene) {
        final ObjectProperty<Point2D> mouseLocation = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> mouseLocation.set(new Point2D(event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY())));
        scene.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            double mouseX = event.getScreenX();
            double mouseY = event.getScreenY();
            double deltaX = mouseX - mouseLocation.get().getX();
            double deltaY = mouseY - mouseLocation.get().getY();
            Window window = scene.getWindow();
            window.setX(window.getX() + deltaX);
            window.setY(window.getY() + deltaY);
            mouseLocation.set(new Point2D(mouseX, mouseY));
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I found many errors into you example. Can someone help me to debug it?

Comment: I copied it directly from Eclipse. It compiles and runs fine. Make sure you are using JDK 8.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest just using GaussianBlur on your root pane.
That should work in JavaFx 2 as well.

```
GaussianBlur blurEffect = new GaussianBlur(5);
root.setEffect(blurEffect);
```

That's it! For further information read the Javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/effect/GaussianBlur.html
Hope it helps,
Laurenz

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need waste your time to make custom Modal ,you can use JFXDialog from [JFoenix](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) ,it is easy to implement ,this example can help you :

```
private void alert(String title, String messageContent) {
        JFXDialog uploadingErrorDialog = new JFXDialog();
        //Dialog components
        Text titleText = new Text(title);
        Text contentText = new Text(messageContent);

        JFXDialogLayout dialogLayout = new JFXDialogLayout();
        dialogLayout.setHeading(titleText);
        dialogLayout.setBody(contentText);
        //Create close button
        JFXButton closeButton = new JFXButton(SignUpFormStrings.getDialogCloseButton());
        closeButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            uploadingErrorDialog.close();
        });
        dialogLayout.setActions(closeButton);
        uploadingErrorDialog.getStylesheets().add(Indigo.class.getClass().getResource("/mvc/view/css/signupform.css").toExternalForm());
        uploadingErrorDialog.setDialogContainer((StackPane) createAccountButton.getParent().getScene().getRoot());
        uploadingErrorDialog.setContent(dialogLayout);
        uploadingErrorDialog.show();
    }
```

And the result is pretty :

[image]