# How can i add shadow for undecorated stage with JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

What i see:

[image]

What i want to see:

[image]

I tried to add shadow with `css` but effect was visible *only* in SceneBuilder. Program window was shown *without* shadow.

```
.rootBorder {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 10, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

How can i add some shadow to the stage? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

What's happening is that the shadow is being clipped off at the edge of the stage. If your root node is an instance of Region (which includes all the layouts) you can add padding.

```
region.setPadding(new Insets(20,20,20,20));
```

Then the drop shadow should appear. If the CSS doesn't work, you can also add the drop shadow in the code itself with:

```
stage.getScene().getRoot().setEffect(new DropShadow());
```

Edit:
The scene will need to be transparent as well.

```
stage.getScene().setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Root node of my application is BorderPane. And if I apply padding to it I see something like that: http://screencloud.net/v/gzgS No transparency. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I forgot to set the scene to transparent. Use `stage.getScene().setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Comment: I tried again on a new project. Does not exceed. Here's the source code: http://pastebin.com/mEBesH9P

Comment: Try adding the stylesheet to the scene instead of the BorderPane then make the BorderPane a custom style class in the stylesheet. Here's the edited source code: http://pastebin.com/Luhp8Gzs

Comment: Unfortunately, not working. But I found a solution and write the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571593/drop-shadow-in-an-undecorated-pane-javafx

Comment: The Insets need to go on the BackgroundFill padding, not the Region padding.  Also, the StageStyle needs to be Transparent.  This answer only shows the Transparent Scene Fill.