# Transparent background in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

So I know this has been discussed in different threads already, but sadly I haven't found a working solution yet, altough I tried alot, even with chatGPT, which ended in it assuming, there is something wrong with my graphics board, which I dont think so.

I'm tryin to reach a transparent background of my stage or scene or of the rootpane of that scene. I sadly can not identify the mistake's source further.
Here is what I've got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="root" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="480.0" styleClass="foreground-pane" stylesheets="@../css/button-styles.css, @../css/window-styles.css, @../css/controller-styles.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fx.controller.CreatorDialogue">
   <children>
      <ListView fx:id="itemList" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="620.0" styleClass="creator-list-view" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0" />
      <Button fx:id="cancelButton" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="676.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="90.0" styleClass="creation-right-aligned-button" text="Cancel">
         ...
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="createButton" layoutX="257.0" layoutY="676.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="90.0" styleClass="creation-right-aligned-button" text="Create">
         ...
      </Button>
      <Group fx:id="itemMenu" layoutX="19.0" layoutY="526.0">
         ...
      </Group>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This is the FXML logic of a scene that I'm loading on a modal stage, that is opened upon an underlying stage, which is set to be "unresponsive" for the time, the modal stage is opened.
Thats how I did it:

```
Stage primaryStage = (Stage)((Node)(mouseEvent.getSource())).getScene().getWindow();

HashMapStage modalStage = new HashMapStage();

modalStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
modalStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
modalStage.setOpacity(0.9);

FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Run.class.getResource("creator-dialogue.fxml"));
Scene creatorDialogue = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 480, 720);
creatorDialogue.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

modalStage.setScene(creatorDialogue);
modalStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
modalStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
modalStage.setResizable(false);
modalStage.centerOnScreen();

modalStage.showAndWait();
```

I want this modal stage to have round corners, which I already reached with the common `-fx-background-radius: 20;` and to make sure aswell `-fx-border-radius: 20;`.
I have set the `-fx-background-color: #737A83`, which is a dark grey. I did this in a custom style class `.foreground-pane` that I assigned to the anchor pane with `fx:id="root"`.

As shown above I also made the stage transparent & undecorated and set the fill to `Color.TRANSPARENT`.

Somehow I still have a white background "filling" the rounded corners:
[image]

I also tried to add another larger anchor pane with `-fx-background-color: transparent` as root pane (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31687182/18737461)) and place the current root pane on that but it seems like the root-panes-transparency is always white instead of transparent. That also happens when I change the background color of my current root pane to transparent.

So I thought, alright, must have something to do with the stage's or scene's transparency, but as shown above I also tried to make these transparent as far as I could with my knowledge.

Maybe someone here finds the (maybe really stupid) mistake I made. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Don't know exactly why, but using only `modalStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);`

instead of both

```
modalStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
modalStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

did the trick.

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to call `initStyle()` twice. It can only have one style.